# SQL Server 2008 in Windows 8

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008

I installed Windows 8 on my laptop and I'm going through installing my software.  I just installed SQL Server 2008 R2, but none of the logon information I supplied will allow me to logon.  I'm not sure what the problem is.  I tried using Windows authentication and SQL Authentication.  I didn't have this problem installing on Windows 7.  Has anyone else gone through this?

Comment: Did you set it up for windows auth or mixed mode?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The problem was, I was trying to connect to the instance name.  I needed to connect to .\[Instance Name].  You provided good information I will likely need in the future.

Comment: How exactly were you able to install it?! I keep on getting an error telling me I'm installing a copy of SQL Server with a language that is different from the OS language! the only problem is, the OS default language is English, and the installer I am using is English ... SO I don't know what is I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: I would suggest you post this to the board.  Since this question was already answered, I'm not sure anyone will look at this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are an admin on your machine, you can start it in [single user mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188236.aspx) and then it's a simple matter of fixing it - [Connecting to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx)